# Passing data form a component to layout file through expo-router

Tags: typescript, react-native, layout, expo, expo-router

I want to pass a prop (**accountInfo**) from a component to the layout file of the app. The component which has the `accountInfo` is dynamically routed i.e. `app/[accId]/index.tsx`. I have different layouts for different routes in the root `_layout.tsx` file.

**_layout.tsx:**

```
import { ErrorBoundaryProps, Stack, useNavigation } from "expo-router";
import CustomHeader from "@/Components/CustomHeader";
import { BottomSheetModalProvider } from "@gorhom/bottom-sheet";
import Colors from "../constants/Colors";
import { TouchableOpacity, View, StyleSheet, Text, Linking } from "react-native";
import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { SvgUri } from "react-native-svg";

export const unstable_settings = {
  // Ensure that reloading on `/modal` keeps a back button present.
  initialRouteName: "index",
};

export default function RootLayoutNav() {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const handleEmailPress = () => {
    const email = 'sample@email.com' //TODO: add providers actual data
    Linking.openURL(`mailto:${email}`);
  }

  const handlePhonePress = () => {
    const phoneNumber = '1234567890'; 
    Linking.openURL(`tel:${phoneNumber}`);
  };

  const handleWebsitePress = () => {
    const websiteUrl = 'https://sample.com/'; 
    Linking.openURL(websiteUrl);
  };

  return (
    <BottomSheetModalProvider>
      <Stack>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="index"
          options={{
            header: () => <CustomHeader />,
          }}
        />
         <Stack.Screen
          name="[acctId]/index"
          options={{
            headerTitle: "",
            headerShadowVisible: false,

            headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: Colors.lightGrey,
            },
            headerLeft: () => (
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => {
                  navigation.goBack();
                }}
              >
                <Ionicons
                  name="close-outline"
                  size={28}
                  color={Colors.primary}
                />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            ),
            headerRight: (params) => {

              
              return (
              
            <TouchableOpacity style={{ flexDirection: 'row', marginRight: 15 }}>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleEmailPress}>
                <Ionicons
                    name="mail-outline"
                    size={28}
                    color={Colors.primary}
                    paddingLeft={12}
                  />
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={handlePhonePress}>
                <Ionicons
                    name="ios-call-outline"
                    size={26}
                    color={Colors.primary}
                    paddingLeft={12}
                  />
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleWebsitePress}>
                <Ionicons
                    name="ios-globe-outline"
                    size={28}
                    color={Colors.primary}
                    paddingLeft={12}
                  />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            )
          }
          }}
        />
... other layout Screens
```

**index.tsx:** (app/accId/index.tsx)

```
import { Link, useLocalSearchParams, useNavigation } from "expo-router";
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import {
  Image,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
} from "react-native";
import Animated, {useAnimatedStyle, useSharedValue, withTiming} from "react-native-reanimated";
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native-safe-area-context";
import startCase from "lodash/startCase";
import Stripe from "stripe";

import ParallaxScrollView from "@/Components/ParallaxScrollView";
import Colors from "@/constants/Colors";
import { ProductWithPrice, UnitLabel } from "@/types";


const ProviderComponent = (props: any) => {
  const { acctId } = useLocalSearchParams();
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0);
> const [accountInfo, setAccountInfo] = useState<Stripe.Account | null>(null);
  const [isAccountInfoLoading, setIsAccountInfoLoading] = useState(true);
  const [isAccountInfoError, setIsAccountInfoError] = useState(false);
  const [isProductsInfoError, setIsProductsInfoError] = useState(false);
  const { getAccountById, getProductsByAccountId } = useAppStore();

  const navigation = useNavigation()

  const categories = Object.keys(UnitLabel);

  // Fetch Account Information
  useEffect(() => {
    getAccountById(acctId as string)
      .then((data) => {
        setAccountInfo(data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        errorHandler(error);
        setIsAccountInfoError(true);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setIsAccountInfoLoading(false);
      });
  }, [acctId]);
...
```

I could implement **redux** or any **state management library** for it but I think it would be overkill for this and would make the app load slower. Is there any other more efficient way to handle this?

Comment: did  figure this out?